# How to pull GCP Pub/Sub messages with a python HTTP server?

Tags: python, http, get, client, google-cloud-pubsub

GCP provides a REST API for Pub/Sub: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest

The Python API allows users to pull messages as follows, using the Python library https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/index.html

```
import os
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

topic_name = 'projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic}'.format(
    project_id=os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT'),
    topic='MY_TOPIC_NAME',  # Set this to something appropriate.
)

subscription_name = 'projects/{project_id}/subscriptions/{sub}'.format(
    project_id=os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT'),
    sub='MY_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME',  # Set this to something appropriate.
)

def callback(message):
    print(message.data)
    message.ack()

with pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient() as subscriber:
    subscriber.create_subscription(
        name=subscription_name, topic=topic_name)
    future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_name, callback)
    try:
        future.result()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        future.cancel()
```

Do users have to use this library however?

I would like to use a different HTTP client to parse these messages via GET requests using the Pub/Sub API. In principle, this should be done with something like the `requests` library, using the get method:

```
import requests

x = requests.get(END_POINT)
print(x.status_code)
```

However, will this work with streaming GET requests from Google Pub/Sub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a GET, but a post, and yes you can use API to pull messages. You have the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull#ReceivedMessage)

Don't forget to [ack](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/acknowledge) the messages or to modify the [AckDeadline](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/modifyAckDeadline)

All is API at Google Cloud, but the libraries can help your to perform things easily. but if you prefer reinventing the wheel, why not!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm confused about two things: (1) how is there a "response" to a POST request? Am I missing something? (2) I'm investigating this in Python first, as I need to write the PubSub subscription within a language within does not have a client library, i.e. R

Comment: The response is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull#response-body

Comment: Thanks, I think I have been confused how to work with the "response" for the POST request.